# SQL query returning invalid results

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, average

Bit of a newbie to SQL so I'd appreciate any hints as to where I'm going wrong with this SQL statement.

I have two tables, one named `Hotel` and one named `Review`. They are linked by `HotelID`. I'm trying to return `HotelID`s that are associated with an `OverallRating` greater than or equal to 3 (an attribute in the `Hotel` table) AND an average `Cleanliness` (a `Review` attribute) greater than or equal to 5.

I know for a fact that there are **no** `HotelID` that satisfy both requirements and yet this statement returns a lot of results.

```
SELECT
    Hotel.HotelID
FROM
    Hotel 
    INNER JOIN Review ON Hotel.HotelID = Review.ReviewID 
GROUP BY
    Hotel.HotelID 
HAVING
    ( Hotel.OverallRating >= 3 )
    AND
    ( AVG( NULLIF( Review.Cleanliness, -1 ) ) >= 5);
```

`NULLIF` is being used to exclude values of -1 (signifying no rating left).

Thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am thinking the issue is you `INNER JOIN` statement.  When you are joining two tables together, you want to join them on the data that is related between them.  You are currently joining on `Hotel.HotelID = Review.ReviewID`.  My guess is these are each the primary keys of their respective tables and that ReviewID does not point to a record in Hotel.

Try changing your join to `ON Hotel.HotelID = Review.HotelID`.

Answer (score 2):

Your inner join is wrong.

```
INNER JOIN Review ON Hotel.HotelID = Review.ReviewID
```

should be

```
INNER JOIN Review ON Hotel.HotelID = Review.HotelID
```

Use HotelId not ReviewId in the join

Comment: I'm an idiot, good lord. I fixed that last night and must have not saved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . Summarize the reviews before joining to hotels.  Then, you should also join on the correct key:

```
SELECT h.HotelID
FROM Hotel h JOIN
     (SELECT r.HotelId, AVG(r.Cleanliness) as avg_cleanliness
      FROM Review r
      GROUP BY r.HotelId
     ) r
     ON h.HotelId = r.HotelId
WHERE h.OverallRating >= 3 AND r.avg_cleanliness >= 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a typo or is a Hotel ID stored in the Review.**ReviewID**?

```
INNER JOIN Review ON Hotel.HotelID = Review.HotelID
```

Answer (score -2):

I am new to sql as well, but have you tried using a WHERE statement?

SELECT Hotel.HotelID 
FROM Hotel 
INNER JOIN Review ON Hotel.HotelID = Review.HotelID 
WHERE (Hotel.OverallRating >= 3) AND (AVG(NULLIF(Review.Cleanliness, -1)) >= 5);

Comment: Hello! Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question is very wide. Please, read ["how do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Thanks!